# SqlAlchemy db.Enum: How to detect it and retrieve the values

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I have a function to add a column to a model:

```
def col(_type, label = "", **kwargs):
    c = db.Column(_type, **kwargs)
    c.info = {"label":label, "type":""}
    return c
```

I use it like:

```
    # Job Type
    class JTEnum(enum.Enum):
       full = "ﺖﻣﺎﻣ ﻮﻘﺗ"
       part_time = "ﻦﯿﻤﻫ ﻮﻘﺗ"
       project = "ﭖﺭﻭﮋﻫ ﺎﯾ"

    jobtype = col(db.Enum(JTEnum), "ﻥﻮﻋ ﺶﻐﻟ", unique=False,
            nullable=False,
            default=JTEnum.full.name)
    jobtype.info["choices"] = [(i.name, i.value) for i in JTEnum]
```

I call the `col` function for various columns. I would like to put the last line inside this function and it can be called on Enum type and fill the choices something like:

```
def col(_type, label = "", **kwargs):
    c = db.Column(_type, **kwargs)
    c.info = {"label":label, "type":""}
    if isinstance(_type, db.Enum):
       c.info["choices"] = [(i.name, i.value) for i in _type]
    return c
```

However, it gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'Enum' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `_type` which is `db.Enum` is not iterable. You may refer to `a.type.enum_class` like that: `[(i.name, i.value) for i in a.type.enum_class]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue I'm seeing in your code is that you default to `JTEnum.full.name`, which should be the Enum element not its name, then you need to iterate the underlying Enum class of the SQLAlchemy Enum.

```py
import enum

import sqlalchemy as db


class JTEnum(enum.Enum):
    full = "ﺖﻣﺎﻣ ﻮﻘﺗ"
    part_time = "ﻦﯿﻤﻫ ﻮﻘﺗ"
    project = "ﭖﺭﻭﮋﻫ ﺎﯾ"


def col(_type, label="", **kwargs):
    c = db.Column(_type, **kwargs)
    c.info = {"label": label, "type": ""}
    if isinstance(_type, db.Enum):
        c.info["choices"] = [(i.name, i.value) for i in _type.enum_class]
    return c


c = col(
    db.Enum(JTEnum),
    "ﻥﻮﻋ ﺶﻐﻟ",
    unique=False,
    nullable=False,
    default=JTEnum.full,
)

print(c.info)

# {'label': 'ﻥﻮﻋ ﺶﻐﻟ',
# 'type': '',
# 'choices': [('full', 'ﺖﻣﺎﻣ ﻮﻘﺗ'),
#  ('part_time', 'ﻦﯿﻤﻫ ﻮﻘﺗ'),
#  ('project', 'ﭖﺭﻭﮋﻫ ﺎﯾ')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`_type` which is `db.Enum` is not iterable. You may refer to `_type.enum_class` like that:

```py
def col(_type, label = "", **kwargs):
    c = db.Column(_type, **kwargs)
    c.info = {"label":label, "type":""}
    if isinstance(_type, db.Enum):
       c.info["choices"] = [(i.name, i.value) for i in _type.enum_class]
    return c
```

Comment: by `a` you mean `_type`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Fix'd